# Where to keep dll in a jni program

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to run a java native interface program.When i try to run the program i am getting  error asI run by using C:\Java\bin\java JNITest

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Expecting an absolute path of the library: JNITest
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:806)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
        at JNITest.<clinit>(JNITest.java:5)
```

My program is

```
  public class JNITest {
   static{
     // System.load("/home/user1/
       //  JNI_project/mynativelib.so");
      System.load("JNITest");
   }
  // public native void  LOSSGREENAMPT(TIMEINTERVAL,  STARTINITIALLOSS,double ENDINITIALLOSS,double MOISTUREDEFICIT, double SUCTION,double  CONDUCTIVITY, double STARTINFILTRATION,double  FINALINFILTRATION, double IMPERVIOUSAREARATIO,int NUMBERPRECIP, double PRECIP(1),double  EXCESS(1),int ERRORCODE[4], char ERRORMESSAGE[60],char L_errorMessage[60]); 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
     JNITest test=new JNITest();
      //test.greet();
   }
}
```

What is wrong with my program

Answer (score 1):

`System.load(String filename)` needs the file argument to be the absolute path of the library. Therefore if the complete path of JNITest.dll is `C:\JNITest.dll`, you should call `System.load("C:/JNITest.dll")`.

Comment: I am using a windows machine .so i changed as you said to  System.load("C://JNI_project//JNITest.dll");

Comment: Java automatically converts all '/'s in file paths to '\\'s in Windows machines. You need to use either "C:/JNI_project/JNITest.dll" or "C:\\JNI_project\\JNITest.dll".

Comment: Or you could use `System.loadLibrary()`.